# What is the upload folder path for AWS elastic beanstalk?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, request, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to use Flask request to send a text file to my elastic beanstalk environment, but I’m not sure what the directory for the uploads folder is? Could anyone advise me on the path to this folder?

I’m aware that the preferred method would be to upload straight to S3, but I’m making a python application for IOS and I can’t seem to install the boto3 module on IOS, so I want to send the text file to my elastic beanstalk environment with Flask request and then upload the file to S3 using boto3 from this elastic beanstalk environment.

Any help would be much appreciated! If you have a better solution, do suggest it :)

Comment: What do you meany by "upload path"? Which path? The one where your application is going to be stored?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure - see this code to see what I mean by upload path: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+send+file+in+post+request+in+flask+app

Comment: In the code they pre-define the path as `UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'`. So set it to what you want, e.g. `UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/tmp'`?

Comment: Ok thanks! So would /tmp be the complete path? Sorry I’m fairly new to using AWS and Flask!

Comment: Yes. Its path to standard `tmp` (temprorary) folder on linux.